# Certain Special Characters in _POST field Throws Error in INSERT to MySQL

Tags: mysql, webforms, special-characters

I have a simple web form and a simple backend table in MySQL. I am seeing syntax errors in certain posts due to the presences of special characters.

I am using stripslashes($_POST['form_field']) but I still get errors writing to the database.

I am looking for some quick help here to see if anyone knows of the right PHP function to better cleanse my incoming data prior to writing to the table.

I prefer not to test my form, one-by-one, with every single special character (32 in all) to catch and isolate those that are the culprits.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post your code. Most likely you are not properly escaping anything with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at `mysql_real_escape_string()` - that usually works well.

Comment: Awesome @FreudianSlip. That was the answer!!